# Automatic filter for current month and year in Cognos Report Studio ver 10

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I have a query item which filters records by a date column which is in format `'YYYYMM`'. As of now I have hard coded the value `[DateCol] = '201406'` in `Detail filters` to get the current month and year records. But I want to dynamically have this value change. For next month it should filter records by '201407'. How do I achieve this?
I tried this by dragging the `[DateCol]` in a `Detail filters`:

```
[DateCol] = extract(year, current_date) + extract(month, current_date)
```

But it returned an error:

```
UDA-SQL-0460 The operation "equal" is invalid for the following combination of data types: Character and Integer
```

Please guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another formula

```
[DateCol] = cast(extract(year, current_date) * 100 + extract(month, current_date) as varchar(6))
```

Comment: Oh, that's much neater than mine.  Not sure why I forgot that method.

Comment: Beat me by 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to create what I call a 'month key' which is an integer representation of a year and month. You can then convert this to a char for comparison. It's actually quite simple:

```
extract(year, current_date) * 100 + extract(month, current_date)
```

Multiplying any number by 100 results in adding two zeroes to the end. The current year is 2014 so 2014 times 100 equals 201400. You are then free to add the month to get a 'month key'. 201400 + 6 = 201406. You can then convert this integer to a char and make your comparison. The final filter expression becomes:

```
[DateCol] = cast(extract(year, current_date) * 100 + extract(month, current_date), char(6))
```

Note: The technique of making integer 'keys' for dates can be extended to days as well and has many applications, namely sorting. The following expression will give you an integer 'day key' which retains the numerical order and hierarchy of the original date:

```
extract(year, current_date) * 10000 + extract(month, current_date) * 100 + extract(day, current_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems.
The data type for your DateCol is character.  The extract function is returning integers. 
Secondly, you aren't building your YYYYMM correctly with your extracts.  The way you have it, you extract the year as a number, and add the month to it. You are ending up with something like '201406' = 2020, which isn't going to work. So you'll need to cast both extracts and concatenate those:

```
[DateCol] = cast(extract(year, current_date) as varchar(4)
```

+ cast (extract(month, current_date) as varchar(2))

EDIT:
Actually, it'll probably be more complex than that.  Extract won't return 06 for June, just 6. So you'll need to determine if that extract is one character or two.  If it's one, you'll need to tack a '0' to the front after you cast it. The exact syntax will depend on your database, but something like this:

```
[DateCol] = cast(extract(year, current_date) as varchar(4)
+ case when cast (extract(month, current_date) as varchar(2) = 1
    then '0' + cast (extract(month, current_date) as varchar(2)
  else cast (extract(month, current_date) as varchar(2)
end
```

Comment: thank you @Andrew but I am still getting an error: An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlPrepareWithOptions' status='-120'. I can't see the details of the error as I don't have admin rights.

Comment: I made some changes, may help. I hate when admins prevent developers from seeing error messages. I would suggest that you start by building your expression as a report column instead of a filter.  That way you can see the output of it, to make sure you're getting what you expect.  I won't swear my syntax is correct here, I'm just typing it in here.